# WatchOS 9.1/iOS 16.1 xcodebuild run on Apple Watch fails

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcodebuild, watchos

Recently I updated my devices to the newest version and with this update I am having troubles to run xcodebuild commands when destination is my Apple Watch.

The problem is in the scheme configuration or devices visibility for scheme, or both

it is working when I use generic destination:

`xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj -scheme 'MyApp WatchKit App' -destination generic/platform=watchOS  build`

command I used:

`xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme 'MyApp WatchKit App'  -destination 'platform=watchOS,id=Watch's ID'`

And I see this error:

```
xcodebuild: error: The run destination My iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme 'MyApp WatchKit App'.
(null) needs to connect to determine its availability. 
Check the connection between the device and its companion iPhone, and the connection between the iPhone and Xcode. 
Both devices may also need to be restarted and unlocked.
```

Restarting and unlocking doesn't help.

Comment: Same issue. Please share the the solution if you've found one.